# Using xmlstarlet to convert hundreds of XML documents to tables with different numbers of columns

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have hundreds of XML documents that follow the following pattern:

```
<code_table>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <code>ZMB</code>
      <description>Zambia</description>
      <default>false</default>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </row>
    <row>
      <code>ZWE</code>
      <description>Zimbabwe</description>
      <default>false</default>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </row>
  </rows>
</code_table>
```

However, once I get deeper than the `<row>` element, both the number of elements and their names vary. The structure stays flat though (which is why I'm converting these to tables).

Is there a slick way I can use xmlstarlet to convert the file above into tab delimited if I don't know the number of columns or what their names are? Desired output in the above example would be:

```
ZMB Zambia  false   true
ZWE Zambia  false   true
```

I can accomplish what I need by writing some code to analyze the files and then parsing them, but I'm wondering there's a good way to do it all in one step.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Can you try something like `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "code_table/rows[position()>1]" -m ".//row"   -v 'normalize-space()'   -n file.xml` on your actual files and see if it works?

Comment: Very slick -- exactly what I needed